# A compact subgroup K s.t G/K is diffeo. to a vector space

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I came across a fact that: Every connected  Lie group $G$ possesses a compact subgroup $K$ having the property that $G/K$ is diffeomorphic to a vector space.
I would like to see the proof of this fact. Moreover, does $K$ have to be Lie subgroup?

Comment: A closed subgroup must be a Lie subgroup.

Comment: yes sure since $G$ is Hausdorff.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of the theorem of Malcev Iwasawa: If $K$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$, then $G/K$ is homeomorphic to a vector space.

A. Malcev, On the theory of the Lie groups in the large, Mat.Sbornik N.S. vol. 16 (1945) pp. 163-189

```
K. Iwasawa, , On some types of topological groups, Ann. of Math. vol.50 (1949) pp. 507-558.
```

Comment: "maximal" $\to$ "maximal compact"